# php include with wamp

Tags: php, include, wamp

I'm developing a site on my local wamp stack. I have created an alias to view the site so i go to `localhost/eee/` to view it. Ideally i would like to go to `www.eee.lo` but ever since upgrading to win8 I can't get it to work.

So this is the problem, i'm making modules for the website so i don't have to change all the code etc... And i don't want to have to go around changing all the url's when i migrate to the online server so i'm creating a file called `_control.php` which has this;

```
$_SITELOC = "localhost/eee/";
```

And then each time i want to include a file i will go;

```
include "$_SITELOC/scripts/inc/_header.php";
```

But this doesn't work and i can't work out why as if i `echo` it rather than `include` it and then i take what it prints and put it into the url it goes to the correct file. But it throws errors on the include, it gives two warnins;

```
Warning: include(localhost/eee/scripts/inc/_header.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\Chris\Documents\EEE\Website\Site\index.php on line 3

Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'localhost/eee/scripts/inc/_header.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Users\Chris\Documents\EEE\Website\Site\index.php on line 3
```

I read somewhere that it might be to do with the include path so i tried;

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $_SITELOC."/scripts/inc/");
```

but this too did not work and now i'm not sure where to go.

Thanks, Chris

Comment: If you include a file through a URL you are not including the PHP source code, you are executing the file and including its results. Is that what you really intend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localhost/eee/` is your public address that you can use in your web browser. This public address should more appropriately be written as `http://localhost/eee/`. When you move to web server, you get the public address `http://www.eee.lo/`.

When including files, you have to use file paths. For example, if you have your www (or httpd, whatever) directry in `D:\` on windows, then your include path should start with `D:\www\eee\`.

So, basically you have to use two variables to keep paths.

```
$_SITELOC = "http://localhost/eee/"; //For all URLs used in your HTML document.
$_INCPATH = "D:\www\eee\\";  //For all internal file includes.
```

In practice, you will need both of these, and it is good practice to keep the website address and internal paths out of your main script because when uploaded to remote server, not only your public address changes, but you will also have to deal with absolutely different internal (include) paths.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is basically good, to define one (root) path of the application and include files based on it, but unfortunately you're not doing it quite right. You have basically two ways of doing that.
One way (which I personally find better) is to include local files in your file system, where you can define the root path, i.e. like

```
define ('ROOT', 'your/document/root/path');
// and then include the files
include ROOT . '/' . '/scripts/inc/_header.php';
```

The other way would be to include a web resource, what you're trying to do, but you've forgotten to specify the scheme (protocol) you want to use, i.e.

```
define ('ROOT', 'http://localhost/eee');
// and then include the files
include ROOT . '/' . '/scripts/inc/_header.php';
```

For more information, see the examples, provided by the [documentation for `include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)
**Note:** If you want to include the source of a php file, i.e. file with definitions of functions, etc., use the first approach. Including files, using the second approach will only include the output produced by that file.

Comment: Including remotely (unless PHP parsing is disabled) will include the output of the script execution, not the script source.

Answer (score -1):

If you `include()` a URL, you will (probably) be including the *output* of the script's execution, when you want to include the script's *source*. It seems like you actually want to include by local file system path.

Comment: You *can* include a URL (though the OP's URLs are missing the protocol prefix).

Comment: If you include it by URL, you'll include the output of the file execution, not the source.

Comment: Of course, you can include an URL, see the examples http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: `include()` works with URLs, but you have to use proper protocols. Merely `localhost/` is not sufficient. Also, the point of the question is not using URLs in include, its just a bug or confusion on the questioner's end.

Comment: @Adrian I changed the url form to the complete file system path and it now includes the file without any errors. If now I have a link tag to include a style sheet it wants the href which surely is in url form? How would i solve this now as the filesystem path doesn't work with this.

Comment: Correct - links in the HTML will have to use URLs, while your includes will most likely want to use local paths. You'll need to keep two separate variables, one for base URL and one for base path. You can simplify this somewhat by adding a `<base href="..."/>` tag to the `head` of your HTML.

Comment: PS: Thanks for the downvotes on the answer that actually solved the problem.